# How to get width and height of canvas after resizing the browser

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I want to get width and height of canvas which is responsive. I have 5 canvas elements on a single page.

Using Javascript before drawing I want to know the height and width of canvas to be able to draw images at the right size.

HTML Code:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class='all'>
    <canvas id='clock1' style="border:solid">
  </div>
  <div class='all'>
    <canvas id='clock2' style="border:solid">
  </div>
  <div class='all'>
    <canvas id='clock3' style="border:solid">
  </div>
  <div class='all'>
    <canvas id='clock4' style="border:solid">
  </div>
  <div class='all'>
    <canvas id='clock5' style="border:solid">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.all
{
    width:30%;
    height:45%;
    float:left;
}

canvas
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you don't set size of canvas using CSS but calculating the w/h and use the width and height properties.

But if you use CSS you can get the calculated size of the canvas *element* set by CSS using `getComputedStyle()`:

### [Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Nd7t8/)

```
var cs     = getComputedStyle(canvas);
var width  = parseInt( cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
var height = parseInt( cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
```

the size is here returned by `getPropertyValue()` as a string and in pixel size (ie. "400px"), so we use `parseInt()` to chop of the "px" part.

Then simply set the width and height on canvas and update its content.

Full example (adjust as needed):

```
window.onresize = updateCanvas;

updateCanvas();

function updateCanvas() {

    var cs = getComputedStyle(canvas);
    var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
    var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
    
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(width, height);
    ctx.moveTo(0, height);
    ctx.lineTo(width, 0);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Ok 1st Problem Solved. But Using Width And Height I Am Unable To Draw Circle Image Link : http://192.168.10.29/1.png When i Change The Style Of Div ie height And Width % Circle Is Drawn Differently

Comment: @Chintan_chiku I would perhaps suggest open a new question with this specific problem. The link is to your intranet so I couldn't see it, but you can use, in general, drawImage(img, x, y, width, height) to change size of a drawn image.